# RevTex 4-1 Cannot use footnotes?

Tags: bibtex, footnotes, revtex

If I use `\footnote{text}` anywhere in a revtex document (4-1), the document will refuse to compile on an undefined argument error and cannot be made to compile even if you comment the footnote without deleting every file other than the `.tex` file and recompiling from scratch. What is going on?

It is something to do with an interaction between bibtex and `revtex`; if you remove the bibliography it compiles fine. In my short example it points to line 33, even though the example is only 26 lines long, so this number is meaningless.

Error: `! Undefined control sequence.<argument> $\DOTSI \intop \ilimits@ _{-\infty }^\infty e^{-\protect \mathac... determinant.}`

```
  \documentclass[12pt,preprint,longbibliography,aps,prl]{revtex4-1}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subfigure}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{color}

\begin{document}

\title{stuffing}
\author{John doe}

\begin{abstract}
stuff stuff stuff
\end{abstract}

\maketitle
\appendix
\section{Introduction}
where the integral \cite{pairwiseonly} is evaluated over all possible particle positions.\footnote{$\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}+\vec{B}^T \vec{x}} d^nx= \sqrt{ \frac{(\pi)^n}{\det{A}} }e^{\frac{1}{4}\vec{B}^{T}A^{-1}\vec{B}}$. This can be verified by applying the unitary transform $a^\dagger a = 1$, where this diagonalizes A, and then performing the integral in eigenspace. Such a transformation does not change the determinant.}

\section*{References}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev}
\bibliography{hydrodynamics}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add a [compilable minimal working example](http://theoval.cmp.uea.ac.uk/~nlct/latex/minexample/index.html) to let us know what is going on. Otherwise, everything will be guesswork. In this case, i can't even guess.

Comment: Related: [How to insert footnotes in revtex4-1 latex layout](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/335603/106162)

Answer (score 3):

`revtex4-1` acts on footnotes in a quite strange way, saving them for printing in the references section

Use `\protect\int`:

```
positions.\footnote{%
  $\protect\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-\vec{x}^T A \vec{x}+\vec{B}^T \vec{x}} d^nx=
   \sqrt{\frac{(\pi)^n}{\det{A}} }e^{\frac{1}{4}\vec{B}^{T}A^{-1}\vec{B}}$. 
  This can be verified by applying the unitary transform $a^\dagger a = 1$, where
this diagonalizes $A$, and then performing the integral in eigenspace.
Such a transformation does not change the determinant.}
```

Comment: This removes the error, but this is not the behavior I want (since this footnote is in an appendix, I do not want it to show up in the bibliography, which may appear without the appendix). A footnote should appear in the footer of the relevant page. Why did they set things up like this?

Comment: @Elliot I don't know; but if you have to use `revtex4-1` for submitting a paper, do as *they* want. Otherwise, don't use `revtex4-1`.

Answer (score 3):

Use [nofootinbib] option:
`\documentclass[nofootinbib,12pt,preprint,longbibliography,aps,prl]{revtex4-1}`

This puts the footnote at the bottom of the page.

Thanks @egreg. I had the same problem and \protect\int removed the error

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. I'm not sure: Does your answer actually add something new or is it just to confirm that egreg's solution is correct?