# How to insert footnotes in revtex4-1 latex layout

Tags: footnotes, revtex

I am trying to insert a footnote at the end of my sentence using `\footnote{some text}`, however, when I compile the file, I see [?] instead of the footnote. I am using aps template in revtex4-1. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you running `latex bibtex latex latex`?

Comment: I fear I do not know the answer. I am using Texmaker if that helps! Im sorry I just started using LaTex.

Comment: Try pressing F6 F11 F6 F6, does that display anything?  Alternatively try adding the `nofootinbib` and repeatedly compiling.  Both should show something.

Comment: Pressing F11 says "This is BibTex"

Answer (score 19, accepted):

By default `revtex` places footnotes in the bibliography (see e.g. [How to refer to same footnote twice in REVTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/187863/106162)) - in order to make them appear you therefore need to run `bibtex` in the normal fashion (even if you have no actual citations and no proper bibliography) as described in [Question mark or bold citation key instead of citation number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852/106162).

Alternatively you can disable the normal behaviour of `revtex` by using the class option `nofootinbib`.  Apply this class option and you should be able to simply run latex repeatedly to generate a standard bottom of page footnote.

Comment: Thank you so much. May I ask how you apply nofootinbib?

Comment: It's an option to the `revtex` class, i.e.`\documentclass[nofootinbib]{revtex4-1}`

Comment: this is a beautiful answer +1